# as.Date.numeric requires origin in Linux, not Windows.  Fix?

Tags: r

`as.Date(10000)` works fine in Windows, but on a Linux distribution it errors: `'origin' must be supplied`.  Somehow the Windows installation has a default origin?  I'm trying to build/check a package on Linux that was originally developed on a Windows machine.  This package omits the `origin` parameter all over the place.  Is there a quick fix?  Perhaps an addition to Rprofile.site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the zoo package. It provides a version of `as.Date.numeric` with a default origin, e.g.

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(0)
```

Comment: that's the issue!  Sometimes I'm loading zoo

Answer (score 2):

You must be running an older version of R on your windows machine.  `as.Date(10000)` does not work for me on Windows XP running R-2.13.1.

Comment: It seems that sometimes I load zoo which provides a default and that's why I'm seeing this error.

Comment: 64-bit R 2.13.1 on Windows 7 too, `as.Date(10000)` doesn't work. Maybe you have `zoo` loaded in Windows session?

Comment: @SFun28 So you could answer your own question.

Comment: correct...I had zoo loaded.  G. Grothendieck's answer clued me into that.  thanks!